# Android - ParseQuery - Hashmap : Hashmap stays empty?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am having a problem to implement a `ParseQuery` in a `HashMap`. My code is as follows:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> portfoliodata;
public HashMap getPoints() {

    try {
        ParseQuery<RoyalPoints> pointsQuery = RoyalPoints.getQuery();
        pointsQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        List<RoyalPoints> list = pointsQuery.find();
        portfoliodata = new HashMap<>();
        for (RoyalPoints obj : list) {
            portfoliodata.put(obj.getString("business"), portfoliodata.get(obj.getString("business")) + obj.getInt("points"));
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.d("Points retrieval", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return portfoliodata;
}
```

Yet, my result is empty even though `obj.getString("business")` and `obj.getInt("points")` give results and no errors are generated. Any idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there should be errors.
On the first run through the loop, you execute:

```
portfoliodata.put(
  obj.getString("business"),
  portfoliodata.get(obj.getString("business")) + obj.getInt("points"));
```

where `portfoliodata.get(obj.getString("business"))` would give you a `null` (because the map is empty), and adding that to an `int` should throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Even changing this line to `portfoliodata.put(obj.getString("business"), obj.getInt("points"));` gives me an empty Hashmap even though it shouldn't then.

Comment: Ok, now it's strange. I'd say do more log printing in the loop, for each `obj`. Also, note that your `HashMap` is declared outside the function, so if you're using the field rather than the return value, you're always seeing the most recent results.